# How to add Secure Certificate to App Service

Tags: azure

I am somewhat new to websites and I have created a Wordpress website from marketplace on azure app service.
Can someone help me on how to add SSL certificate to it?

I have no way so war but I want to add SSL certificate added to Website.

Comment: see: [Secure connections by adding and managing TLS/SSL certificates in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have purchased an App Service certificate which is private certificate that's managed by Azure. It combines the simplicity of automated certificate management and the flexibility of renewal and export options. Refer to these step by step document: [Import an App Service Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#import-an-app-service-certificate)

If you already have a private certificate from a third-party provider, you can upload by following this document:

[Upload a private certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#upload-a-private-certificate) Also, See [Private certificate requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#private-certificate-requirements).